# Linq to SharePoint with Distinct Results

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm making an alphabetical search filter, and want to get the results from a list and only show the available letter filters based on what results are in the list.  Now the tricky part, the desired column is a people field, and I only want to get the first letter of the person's name.

Right now I can use the following code to query a letter, but who wants to run 26 queries and slow  page loads.  In addition, all the results will show of users that start with the letter a.  So I guess I could do a limit to return only one result, if this was the only option.

```
SPList UserActivity = web.Lists["User Activity"];

var varUserActivity = (from SPListItem UserActivityItem in UserActivity.Items
                    where UserActivityItem["Username"].ToString().Substring(UserActivityItem["Username"].ToString().IndexOf('#') + 1, (UserActivityItem["Username"].ToString().Length - UserActivityItem["Username"].ToString().IndexOf('#')) - 1).ToLower().Replace("domain\\","").StartsWith("a")
                    select UserActivityItem);

foreach (SPListItem uaitem in varUserActivity)
{
    this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(uaitem["Username"].ToString() + "<br>"));
}
```

But I prefer to run one query, returning one result for each unique letter.  With this list example data:

1. DOMAIN\Terra Branford
2. DOMAIN\Locke Cole
3. DOMAIN\Sabin Figaro
4. DOMAIN\Setzer Gabbiani
5. DOMAIN\Cyan Garamonde
6. DOMAIN\Celes Chere
7. DOMAIN\Cid Marquez

...the results expected to return are:

1. DOMAIN\Terra Branford
2. DOMAIN\Locke Cole
3. DOMAIN\Sabin Figaro
4. DOMAIN\Cyan Garamonde

From here I can build my filter with the letters: C L R S.  So my question is how do I create a distinct Linq query that returns results based on first letter?

Comment: That's not a LINQ to sharepoint query.  You're just pulling the entire list's items into memory and doing all of that filtering on the application side.  Having said that, I'm fairly confident that it's impossible to write this query in CAML, so you won't have any means of doing anything else.  Still, you should recognize that you're not actually doing any DB filtering.  One thing you *can* do though is set `ViewFields` to only fetch the columns that you need.

Comment: Agreed, CAML just won't do.  Setting ViewFields will help decrease the loads, but what about returning DISTINCT results?

Comment: It ceaces to become a SharePoint problem.  Extract out the username, and then it becomes simply getting distinct first letters of the username given a sequence of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out:

1. Use /14/bin/SPMetal.exe to export the site URL into a DataContext class file
2. Import that *.cs class file into your project (find in /14/bin/)
3. Add references
4. Start Linq to SP using your DataContext
5. Query to your heart's content

Here's an example of table data:

1. DOMAIN\Terra Branford
2. DOMAIN\Locke Cole
3. DOMAIN\Sabin Figaro
4. DOMAIN\Setzer Gabbiani
5. DOMAIN\Cyan Garamonde
6. DOMAIN\Celes Chere
7. DOMAIN\Cid Marquez

Here's the data filtering code:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq;

MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext("http://localhost");
var varUserActivity = (from item in dc.UserActivityList
                       orderby item.UsernameName.ToString().Substring(item.UsernameName.ToString().IndexOf('#') + 1, 1).ToLower().Replace("domain\\", "") ascending
                       select new { letter = item.UsernameName.ToString().Substring(item.UsernameName.ToString().IndexOf('#') + 1, 1).ToLower().Replace("domain\\", "") }).Distinct();

foreach (var uaitem in varUserActivity)
{
    this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(uaitem.letter + "<br>"));
}
```

So what's happening in this code is it queries a single people column in a list, strips out the domain, returns the first letter of the account name, sorts ascending and returns distinct letters.  So the result with the above table data will show:

1. c
2. l
3. s
4. t

This is perfect for making an alphabetic filter.  I'm not completely sure if it's doing real data filtering or not, but it sure beats doing 26 different queries by letter.